# Show that $d_x : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,d) be a metric space, $x \in X$, $r>0$.

Show that $d_x : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $d_x(y) = d(x,y)$ is a continuous function

Since X and $\mathbb{R}$ are both metric  spaces I will try to show continuity using the following definition:
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 s.t. \forall y \in X d(y,y') < \delta \implies d_{\mathbb{R}} (d_x(y),d_x(y'))< \epsilon$

$\iff$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 s.t. \forall y \in X d(y,y') < \delta \implies \mid d_x(y)-d_x(y')\mid< \epsilon$ (I supposed that the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is $d_{\mathbb{R}}(x,y) = \mid x - y \mid$)

$\iff$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 s.t. \forall y \in X d(y,y') < \delta \implies \mid d(x,y)-d(x,y')\mid< \epsilon$

**Questions**

I am kind of stuck and I have 2 questions:

- Am I going the right direction
- I feel like I should compare $d(y,y')$ and $\mid d(x,y)-d(x,y')\mid$ But don't know how

Comment: Hint: Use the reverse triangle inequality!

Comment: @sranthrop Where can i find a proof of that inequlity?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is totally fine. Just use the reverse triangle inequality:
$$
|d(x,y)-d(x,y')|\leq d(y,y').
$$
Your desired estimate follows immediately.

Comment: Where could I find a proof of that inequality?

Comment: It is a very simple consequence of the ordinary triangle inequality. Start by rewriting $|A| \le B$ in the form $-B \le A \le B$...

Comment: I recommend you to try to prove it first on your own. It is an easy consequence of the regular triangle inequality. If you get stuck you can also look here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $(x_n,y_n)_n$ be a sequence (in $X\times X$) satisfying $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ and $y_{n}\rightarrow y$. Then, 
$$d(x_{n},y_{n})\leq d(x_{n},x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y_{n})\phantom{.}$$
and
$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_{n})+d(x_{n},y_{n})+d(y_{n},y).$$
Can you use these inequalities to show $d(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow d(x,y)$?